# Nonexistence of spherical objects

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

This is example 8.10(vi) (on page 170-171) in Huybreachts' Fourier-Mukai transform in algebraic geometry. Let $X$ be a variety of dimension at least three with nontrivial $H^2(X,O_X)$. I want to show $X$ has no spherical object with nontrivial rank. In the book he said that this is because $Ext^2(E,E)\rightarrow H^2(X,O_X)$ is surjective for $rk(E)\neq0$ and $E$ is a complex of coherent sheaves (which is induced by the trace map) and thus it dos not exist. Howenver, I do not know why the given map above is surjective.

Comment: Huybrecht's has a number of books; you'll have better luck getting a response if you mention which one (*Fourier-Mukai...*?)

Comment: @TabesBridges Sorry for my mistake. It is Fourier-Muaki. I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{Ext}^2(E,E)=H^2(E^*\otimes E)$ for any vector bundle. The trace map gives $E^*\otimes E\to O$ which splits ($E\neq 0$) and thus the above map is surjective.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, in my case $E$ is a complex of coherent sheaves (I shall add it in the question). so how should I define the split map? Thank you.

Comment: @PeterLiu: The argument for complexes is the same: the composition of the natural maps $$\mathcal{O} \to E^* \otimes E \to \mathcal{O}$$ is equal to the multiplication by the rank of the complex $E$, so if it is non-zero, $\mathcal{O}$ is a direct summand of $E^* \otimes E$.